# jQuery - Field values and comparisons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a form validation and want to check a number of radio button values. By default no values are selected. There are two options for each question - yes and no.

First I hide the 'caution message' and check whenever one of the inputs are changed. What I want to happen is when all options are set to no (value is N), then the error message will show, otherwise it will hide. I want it so that if any of the options are then changed to yes the error message will hide. What happens here is if any of the values are changed to yes the error message shows. Maybe I'm over complicating how this should work?

```
$('.cautionMessage').hide();
$('.weeeDetailsChange input').change(function () {
    var ownBrand = $('input[name="ownbrand"]:checked').val();
    var resell = $('input[name="resell"]:checked').val();
    var ImportBasis = $('input[name="importbasis"]:checked').val();
    var distributeEEE = $('input[name="distributeeee"]:checked').val();
    var exportEU = $('input[name="exporteu"]:checked').val();
    var distanceSelling = $('input[name="distanceselling"]:checked').val();

    if ( ownBrand && resell && ImportBasis && distributeEEE && exportEU && distanceSelling === 'Y' ) {
        $('.cautionMessage').show();
        console.log('Show');
    } else {
        $('.cautionMessage').hide();
        console.log('Hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: By the way, the reason `ImportBasis` is blue-greenish in the code above is because by convention names that start with a capital letter are for constructor functions... you should change it to `importBasis`. Just an aside. SECOND - you only check `distanceSelling` against `"Y"` but none of the others(?)! If those DOM elements exist at all the first 90% of your `if`statement will always be `true` and the entire statement only hinges on `distanceSelling`.

Comment: You are totally correct, thanks for your comment. I notice the highlighting as well in stackoverflow's editor but it didn't change in my code editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I see what's happening -- probably just needed a fresh set of eyes on this.

What you're currently doing is checking that only **distanceSelling** is *yes* whereas you should be checking that all values are *no* and running your show/hide based on that since you want to show the message if any of the values are 'yes'.

Try the following:

```
$('.cautionMessage').hide();
$('.weeeDetailsChange input').change(function () {
    var ownBrand = $('input[name="ownbrand"]:checked').val();
    var resell = $('input[name="resell"]:checked').val();
    var ImportBasis = $('input[name="importbasis"]:checked').val();
    var distributeEEE = $('input[name="distributeeee"]:checked').val();
    var exportEU = $('input[name="exporteu"]:checked').val();
    var distanceSelling = $('input[name="distanceselling"]:checked').val();

    if (ownBrand == 'N' && resell == 'N' && ImportBasis == 'N' && distributeEEE == 'N' && exportEU == 'N' && distanceSelling == 'N' ) {
        // all values are 'N'
        $('.cautionMessage').show();
        console.log('Show');
    } else {
        // not all values are 'N'
        $('.cautionMessage').hide();
        console.log('Hide');
    }
});
```

I hope I understood that correctly. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! This almost works correctly. If no values have been selected and I select any radio button to no, the error message appears. The code only works as expected when all radio buttons have been checked. Any ideas?

Comment: editted the code -- should work as expected now. now it's checking that all boxes are 'N' and not that everything is not 'Y' -- let me know if it works!

Comment: That is correct and works perfectly, thank you! Okay I've learned my lesson with comparison operators. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes that I made. I use the property checked `prop('checked')` instead of `val()` because it actually returns me a Boolean so I do not need to compare it to `y` or anything. I then flip the hide and show where the caution message is only hidden when all check boxes are check. [Click here to see example](http://jsfiddle.net/j4hgz/7/)

```
$('.caution').hide();
$(".weeeDetailsChange").change(function(){
var ownBrand =  $('input[name="ownbrand"]:checked').prop('checked')
var resell =$('input[name="resell"]:checked').prop('checked')
var ImportBasis = $('input[name="importbasis"]:checked').prop('checked')
var distributeEEE = $('input[name="distributeeee"]:checked').prop('checked')
var exportEU = $('input[name="exporteu"]:checked').prop('checked')
var distanceSelling = $('input[name="distanceselling"]:checked').prop('checked')

if ( ownBrand && resell && ImportBasis && distributeEEE && exportEU && distanceSelling) {
    $('.caution').hide();
    console.log('hide');
} else {
    $('.caution').show();
    console.log('show');
}
});
```

Comment: This also works and I never really used the prop method before. Thanks for this alternative option.